# How to make CMD+Tab show current window

Tags: macos, window-manager, preferences

The most ongoing annoying thing about OSX is that I'll switch to an app with CMD+Tab and it only shows the top menu bar.  How do I make it also show the current window like it does in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you minimize the app with the yellow dot it the window left top, then you'll not get the window shown again - unless you with the mouse click on the app icon in the dock.

BUT - if you minimize the app with CMD+H, then you'll get the window shown again with CMD+TAB